# How to add the operators increment (++), decrement (--) and or (||) in the method: AddTokenRule

Tags: c#, lexer, lexical-analysis

I am doing a lexical analyzer which identifies the entered words and until the moment I have gone well with other operators but now I need help to add the operators or(||), increment(++) and decrement(--) to the method: `AddTokenRule`
What would be the correct regular expression?

The `AddTokenRule` method adds a pattern to recognize, we must indicate the first regular expression, followed by a name for the token and finally an optional `bool` type value that indicates if the corresponding token should be ignored.

```
csLexer.AddTokenRule (@ "\ s +", "SPACE", true);
csLexer.AddTokenRule (@ "\ b [_a-zA-Z] [\ w] * \ b", "IDENTIFIER");
csLexer.AddTokenRule (@ "[- \ + \ * \ /]", "OPERATOR_ARITMETIC"); //This is where I need help to add the operator increment (++) and decrement (--)
csLexer.AddTokenRule (@ "== |> = | <= | <|> |! =", "OPERATOR_RELATIONAL");
csLexer.AddTokenRule (@ "&& |!", "OPERATOR_LOGIC"); //This is where I need help to add the operator || (or)
```

I hope that the output expression can contain the operator in the same line or in a new line:
`csLexer.AddTokenRule (@ "help", "OPERATOR_NEW");`

Comment: Not sure what you're asking for here, are you asking for a regular expression that will match the ++, -- or || operators? How about `@"\+\+|--|\|\|"` ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your contribution helped me a lot. I tell you that when I execute your expression, it is carried out successfully. But my lexical analyzer fails in the expressions alone of the operators sum (+) and subtraction (-).
@ "\ + \ + | - | \ | \ |" perfect. 
<@ "[- \ + \ * \ /]", "OPERATOR_ARITMETIC") does not identify the sum (+) alone, nor does it identify the subtraction (-) alone.

I am looking for the lexical analyzer to identify everyone equally, both: (++), (+), (-) and (-)

Comment: Then you need to add those, you can either do `\+\+?` to signal that the last `+` sign is optional, or just add another case: `\+\+|\+|...`

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Finally I stay like this:
(@ "\ + \ + | \ + | - | \ - | \ * | \ /", "OPERATOR_ARITHMETIC");
(@ "\ = \ = | \ = |> = | <= | <|> |! =", "OPERATOR_RELATIONAL");
(@ "&& |! | \ | \ |", "OPERATOR_LOGIC");